# Pass list of Strings to gradle task property without using parentheses

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have a `build.gradle` like so, with a tiny little custom task:

```
task ListOfStrings(type: ExampleTask, description: 'Prove we can pass string list without parentheses') {
    TheList ('one', 'two', 'three') // this works but it's not beautiful
}
public class ExampleTask extends DefaultTask {
    public void TheList(String... theStrings) {
        theStrings.each {
            println it
        }
    }
}
```

In the `test.testLogging` block is `events`: and we can pass a comma-separated list of strings **without parentheses**.

```
test {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams true
        exceptionFormat 'short'
        events 'passed', 'failed', 'skipped' // this is beautiful
    }
}
```

My question is: how do I write my `ExampleTask` so I can write `TheList` as a simple list of comma-separated strings **omitting the parentheses**?

My perfect-world scenario is to be able to express the task like so:

```
task ListOfStrings(type: ExampleTask, description: 'Prove we can pass string list without parentheses') {
    TheList 'one', 'two', 'three'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not true that you need to define custom DSL/extension to solve this problem. You need to define a *method* instead of a *field*. Here's a working  example:

```
task ListOfStrings(type: ExampleTask, description: 'Prove we can pass string list without parentheses') {
    theList 'one', 'two', 'three'
}

public class ExampleTask extends DefaultTask {
    List l = []

    @TaskAction
    void run() {
      l.each { println it }
    }

    public void theList(Object... theStrings) {
        l.addAll(theStrings)
    }
}
```

Comment: The the case of the method name. Magic. Use camelCase and it works, use TitleCase and it's boom.

Comment: Yes, also saw that. Good case for another question.

Answer (score 3):

The example you provided from `test.testlogging` and the code example you are showing are slightly different - in that testlogging is using an extension and you are creating a task. Here's how you can define a custom extension that serves as an input to a task:

```
public class CustomExtension{
    final Project project

    CustomExtension(final Project project) {
        this.project = project
    }

    public void theList(String... theStrings){
        project.tasks.create('printStrings'){
            doLast{
                theStrings.each { println it }
            }
        }
    }
}

project.extensions.create('List', CustomExtension, project)

List{
    theList 'one', 'two', 'three'
}
```

Now running `gradle printStrings` gives:

```
gradle printstrings
:printStrings
one
two
three

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.488 secs
```

Comment: There's no need to define extension.

Comment: You're right @Opal I was going for the style of `test.testlogging` in OPs question. Just realized, that isn't exactly what they're asking for.

Comment: While not answering question exactly, this was helpful. Many thanks @RaGe