# Why does case matter in gradle task method names?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306205/pass-list-of-strings-to-gradle-task-property-without-using-parentheses) I was puzzled because I thought we could pass arguments to methods without parentheses. Indeed, you **can** pass arguments as a comma-separated list to a method like so:

```
task ListOfStrings(type: ExampleTask) {
    //TheList 'one', 'two', 'three' // doesn't work
    theList 'one', 'two', 'three'
}
public class ExampleTask extends DefaultTask {
    //public void TheList(Object... theStrings) {
    //    theStrings.each { println it }
    //}
    public void theList(Object... theStrings) {
        theStrings.each { println it }
    }
}
```

The code above **works** because the method name is **camelCase**. When using a method name that is **TitleCase** (commented out above) then gradle throws up an error:

```
  build file '/tmp/build.gradle': 16: unexpected token: one @ line 16, column 13.
         TheList 'one', 'two', 'three'
                 ^
```

**SO**, the question is, "why does the case of the method name matter?"
Summarily, what is causing this behaviour? Is it a convention? And if so, where is it documented?

Comment: It's Groovy which is Java underneath so it's still case sensitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just the Groovy compiler treating any uppercase symbol as a class reference, rather than a method. There's an ambiguity here that you can fix by either:

- using parenthesis `Foo('one', 'two')`

or

- qualifying the method name `this.Foo 'one', 'two'`.

In general the convention is that classes are capitalized and methods aren't. Because Groovy is a dynamic language the compiler leans heavily on these conventions.

Comment: My friend is a java veteran, and just a few days ago told me that it was "how it is in java world" that methods are lowerCamel - he pointed me at this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367 which, though now out of date, explains the "rules".